# Oracle + C# Picture

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle10g

How can I insert Picture to Oracle DataBase Oracle ?

can I get C# sample code ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 2):

There is an [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ehanth/Csharpdatabse03142006093738AM/Csharpdatabse.aspx?ArticleID=c3fef0d2-f165-4384-a788-cdb860922d8a) showing how to do it.